# C# encrypted Login Password to Compare Values from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, hash

I have and encrypting method incorporated into my program login that Takes the Plain Text Password runs Thru SHA1 Base64 hashing to get a hash then takes the password hash and compares to MySQL database value to See if they match then grants access if they don't match denies access.
My Problem is the C# syntax to call the hashed password then look in mysql Database at this User name and match the password hashes.

Hash from Login == Hash from database im trying to figure out how to do it.

```
private void btn_ProLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = txt_ProgramPass.Text.ToString(); //Password TextBox
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        SHA1 algorithm = SHA1.Create();
        byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(data);
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        //Database Connection query SELECT 'value' From accounts.UPassword
        // then Compare Values if match the allow else Deny access MSG Box Ect
    }
```

The Question im asking is what the syntax is for c# to compare a generated hash from login to database hash previously entered?

P.S. The actual Database info is not included. The Table in DB is accounts Column is UPassword and value is the hash in Database.

Comment: Anything wrong with just using `==` to compare computed value with one that you read from DB?

Comment: I want to use == its just pulling the hash from db to compare to hash generated by pressing login button

Comment: The login button is going to do two things query db for username and hashed password then its goin to take user enter password run it thru the encryption method to generate a has then it takes generated hash and compares to hash pulled from database and allows or denies the user.